# Android 14 Error: But another display has a focused window

Tags: android, samsung-dex

I made an application to create and control UHID mouse on Samsung DeX mode. My app is in user phone screen and the mouse pointer is on DeX screen (TV or monitor). My app has three buttons for left, middle and right click actions.
Everything works fine for Android 13 and earlier Android version. However in Android 14, every time user do click action by touching and then releasing any button on phone srceen, the ACTION_DOWN event is performed but then the action is cancelled (the ACTION_UP event is skipped so the mouse is still in click action - not releasing) and the log shows below error.

> Inputdispatcher: But another display has a focused

I was trying to catch the error with try-catch statements or other ways but could not catch such kind of error.
My questions are if there is way to catch and ignore such error so that the action (ACTION_UP) can be performed. Or if someone has any idea or solution to overcome this issue? Thanks.